# Why my media can't play with AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, media, wma

```
NSString *soundFileURL=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"noise" ofType:@"wma"];

self.noise=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFileURL] error:nil];

[self.noise play];
```

then the main.m have mistake.
When I use short media about 1 sec it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `AVFoundation` can't play Windows Media audio (WMA). Convert your "noise" to a supported format, such as MP3 or AAC.